# Curious Keydown Behavior in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I am trying to create a textbox that is horizontally resizable, draggable, and dynamically changes its height based on what is typed inside.  Here is my code so far

HTML:

```
<div id="text_container">
    <div id="my_text" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#text_container {
    border: #4A4A4A 2px solid;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#my_text {
    width: 100%;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    background: #fff;  
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#text_container').resizable( { handles: 'e' } ).draggable();

$('#my_text').keydown( function() {
    $('#text_container').css( { height: ($( this ).height() + 2) } );
});

$('#text_container').resize( function() {
    $('#text_container').css( { height: ($( '#my_text' ).height() + 2) } );
});
```

This makes the box change correctly with the horizontal resizing, but when I need to have it resize by skipping down a line, I have to type in one more character than I should have to.  Using keypress gives the same results, and keyup doesn't resize until the key has been released, so if a person is holding down a key, it won't resize the div until the person releases the key, which doesn't seem optimal to me.  Any thoughts on this?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UA3QS/65/
​
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input value is not set to the new value in `keydown`. You can use the `keyup` event instead:

```
$('#my_text').keyup( function() {
    $('#text_container').css( { height: ($(this).height() + 2) });
});
```

Comment: Right, but with keyup, if a user holds down a key without releasing it, it will skip to a new line, but the container div won't resize accordingly until they release their key.  Seems like an incomplete solution.  Is there any way to make it change sizes while the key is being held down? Perhaps some combination of keyup and keydown?

Comment: The real solution is to use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input) event, but I don't think jQuery supports it

Comment: @CamdenReslink: try the `keypress` event, this fires every time a character is inserted (i.e. for every repeat when a key is held down). I don't think backspace can be reliably checked for using this event though, so you may want to check for that seperately. See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html